# Was bedeutet es, wenn "warum" auf der ersten Silbe betont wird?

Tags: pronunciation

Hat es eine spezielle Bedeutung, wenn "warum" auf der ersten statt auf der zweiten Silbe betont wird?

Comment: Ich bin nicht damit einverstanden, dass Betonung zu Nuance synomisiert wird.

Comment: Vielleicht sollte man ein eigenständiges tag für "Betonung" einführen, wenn es "Nuance" nicht mehr gibt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das [Digitale Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=warum) erklärt:

> [warum] kann im direkten Fragesatz, wenn nachdrücklich gebraucht, auf der ersten Silbe betont werden.

Also z.B.

> "Wârum hast Du das getan?"

Diese Art der Betonung halte ich aber für sehr selten.

Comment: Es sind ja Fragen, somit geht die Stimme gegen Ende zum Fragezeichen hin wieder nach oben.

Comment: In "Warum hast Du das getan?" geht die Satzmelodie am Ende nicht nach oben, wenn "warum" auf der ersten Silbe betont wird. Es klingt eher wie ein Vorwurf und wird meist mit grosser Entrüstung geäussert. Schon fast rhetorisch.

Comment: Die Betonung auf der ersten Silbe wird auch angewendet, wenn in einem Gespräch der vom Gegenüber angegebene Grund (akkustisch) nicht verstanden wurde: A: *Ich bin gestern zu Hause geblieben, weil...* B: *Warum bist du zu Hause geblieben?*

Comment: @teylyn: +1, wollte ich auch grad schreiben. Ist auf jeden Fall eine klassische "Streitfrage". Eigentlich entspricht es einer harmlosen Nachfrage "Ich habe das getan weil *murmelmurmel*" - "Hmh? Wârum hast du das getan?". Im Streit dann aber rhetorisch / sarkastisch verwendet, als würde man sich dumm stellen oder als hätte der andere es nicht gut genug erklärt (wenn er meistens noch gar nichts gesagt hat): "Und wârum hast du mich nicht einfach angerufen?"

Comment: Ich höre hier diese Betonung häufig als Ausdruck der Verwunderung, gerade auch bei Selbstgesprächen: "Wârum haben wir das (eigentlich) damals so gemacht?" mit einer langgezogenen Frage, die möglicherweise auch keine Antwort erfordert, aber häufig eben doch. Insofern glaube ich, dass der Betonungsunterschied eher subjektiv ist und von sich aus keine Konnotation mitbringt. So gesehen halte ich die Betonung aber auch gar nicht für sooo selten.

Comment: @OrgenGhost: guter Punkt. Insgesamt kann man wohl zusammenfassen, dass die Betonung die Frage nach dem Grund nochmals stärker in den Vordergrund rückt - sei es aus Verwunderung, Ärger oder Sarkasmus.